# Encontrar mas de un caracter en un string

Tags: python

me ha surgido una duda, si quisiera saber todas las posiciones de un caracter en un string en python (en el caso de que se repitiera), cómo podría resolver mi problema?

Comment: `pos = [i for i in range(len(el_string)) if el_string[i]==caracter]`

Comment: Aunque sean preguntas simples, son mejor recibidas si dejas el código que intentaste. Si no intentaste nada, es mejor que busques respuestas en Google o preguntas con mejor suerte en este sitio o su versión en inglés https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo que esta es la manera mas directa y built-in. (inicialmente pensaba con usar algo como `filter(lambda x: x==your_char, your_string)`, pero salia mas complicado porque luego tenias que buscar el indice. (a ver si alguien la puede hacer simple usando eso, tal vez verlo como un numero en binario y obtener las posciones de los `1`)

```
your_string = 'Me gusta el chocolate y el vestido de Ana'
your_char = 'a'
indices = [ ind for ind,cha in enumerate(your_string) if cha==your_char  ]
indices
```

tiene por salida:

```
>>> indices
[7, 18, 40]
```

Si quieres modificarlo para que no sea sensible a mayusculas o minusculas puedes hacer:

`indices = [ ind for ind,cha in enumerate(your_string) if cha.lower()==your_char.lower()  ]`

y la salida seria: `[7, 18, 38, 40]`

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
# Creamos una lista llamada posiciones para almacenarlas
posiciones = []

# Buscar la primera ocurrencia de por ejemplo la letra "a" en el string
pos = string.find("a")

# Mientras se encuentre la letra "a" en el string...
while pos != -1:
  #  Añadimos la posicion a la lista.
  posiciones.append(pos)
  
  # Buscar la siguiente ocurrencia de la letra "a" en el string
  pos = string.find("a", pos + 1)
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##dZBBTsQwDEX3PcWns5kKiDRih9TFwJoTIBYmNdOgNIniFgR3YsEZ5mDF6SyKQLOJZPv75X@nj7GP4WaeZcwuHNCi7un5@EWYAuGNP@uq2uA@Mw1Rlp53MurraaCOkKI462JgQaJMID@Q5UDZk1S/hi0enwrpbhJLGV43sxtYN6KdcuZgHaFj5WXwKw/JxyLyPKqkphocwB4nlwWsxFNhXlzotippCv/BcdAVgbCu2KlUfJ5kjKnee@fLx4KLFte72wrYAPvjN3WuhPZrStCCKhcwKlvzGUqJ1YZ2Gh0siDWquMNUfPGfsOcDLuz/Ea@W9iV2mlXvF8btaqGZ5x8).

Comment: Tenías algunos errores. Quizá lo escribiste mal sin querer. Sé más cuidadoso.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mateo aun soy un principiante en la programacion. Saludos!

Comment: Parece C, no Python.

Comment: Un truco que casi siempre que es posible aplico es probar mi propio código, para que no venga con errores. Espero que este consejo te sea de ayuda!

Comment: @candidmoe si requieres buscar subcadenas (no un solo caracter) esta es la forma mas conveniente, aunque paresca c.